# What is the maximum drive size compatible with the H700 Raid controller for Dell Servers?

Tags: storage, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I am thinking of stuffing twelve 6 TB drives on my R510 server. I know the latest firmware for the H700 controller support more than 2 TB. However, there is no clear documentation on what is the maximum disk size. The lack of documentation makes me assume that there is no limit, except for the highest space drive that can be made today.

Is this true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of me says to check with Dell... Specifically to see what they're selling as an option part for these servers and whether they've validated the use of 6TB disks. I'm assuming you wouldn't be using Dell-sourced drives, though...

In terms of compatibility, 2TB was the big issue for many controllers. Since the H700 has *confirmed* large-drive support (>2TB), there's a strong likelihood that they will work. This depends on the specific disks you use, of course. Some of the drive manufacturers have [controller compatibility lists](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/cs/2579-771897.pdf) as well. So if you have a drive in mind, check to see if it supports your H700.

Comment: You're right, at this point I can only test it out since they are consumer grade (bad bad I know).

Comment: @Carlo71 It will likely work. But which disks are you interested in using? The compatibility list should be available for sure if you're using Western Digital.

Comment: Seagate Desktop Barracuda 4 TB. Haven't found any compatibility lists yet.